# Search and replace post URL's on page output?

Tags: permalinks, filters, seo, mobile, request-filter

Currently, I'm using pretty permalinks for SEO purposes like this: `http://example.com/sample-post`. This is great for search engine ranking, but now I am finding this is not so great for mobile app deep linking and universal links.

I need a path prefix to let my app know it's a post and to handle it as such. This becomes essential with the upcoming iOS universal links and Google App Indexing with Android `http` scheme intents. With just the post slug as the path, there's no way for my app to know that this is a post, page, custom post type, etc.

My thought is to disable permalinks for incoming mobile requests so the post URL's display as the default `http://example.com/?p=124`. Maybe disabling permalinks is not the best course, but perhaps just a filter that intercepts the post URL's on the page output and rewrite them as the default `/?p=124`. But then post links that were manually entered in the content won't change, so a regex to rewrite the URL's maybe needed, but the question again comes up is how do I differentiate post URL's from other site content.

It's seeming more and more that all these years of advocating post name permalinks for SEO are going to haunt us in the era of mobile deep linking and universal links.

Is there a way to search and replace post URL's on the output of pages only for iOS and Android devices?

Comment: What format do you want to rewrite the URL from and to for iOS and Android?

Comment: From http://example.com/sample-post to http://example.com/?p=124. I would even settle to http://example.com/post/sample-post.